# How can i change the format of an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want `A` to simply ouput:
`1 2 3`
when i type `A` in command window.

instead of:

```
  Columns 1 through 3 
  1 2 3
```

because it's giving me a problem when i used huffmanenco function.

Comment: Why would this give a problem? Are you parsing output like this or something? Show some sample code where this output messes up [tag:Matlab] functions please.

Comment: My output is:>> [1 2 3] ans =     1     2     3.  Nothing else

Comment: Please explain "it's giving me a problem when i used huffmanenco function". What problem? Give code that demonstrates it.

Comment: Why should `huffmanenco`'s woring get affected by what is getting printed in the command window? There must be another way to implement the same thing without using the command window output.

Comment: sorry i didn't make myself clear. but I've already sort it out. thanks for responding anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only matter of diplaying the content of the array, you might use:

```
num2str(A)
```

or

```
sprintf('%d ',A)
```

or

```
sprintf('%f ',A)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Preferences>Numeric Display>Compact.

If you are using classes, you can override the `display(s)` function operator...